Problem with running php artisan serve command in laravel once installed yajra and oci8
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [auth] does not exist.

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:940
    936▕ 
    937▕         try {
    938▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    939▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 940▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);        
    941▕         }
    942▕
    943▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    944▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Yajra\Oci8\Oci8ServiceProvider), "Yaj      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Yajra\Oci8\Oci8ServiceProvider), "Yajra\Oci8\Oci8ServiceProvider")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:938
      ReflectionException::("Class "auth" does not exist")

I installed yajra and oci8, then I try to run php artisan serve command but it's showing error.

Is there no reference to a code you wrote in the backtrace ? if so, share that code too.

are you using laravel zero ?
